# c# реализация scaffolding

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scaffolding

Мне необходимо реализовать scaffolding не использую ORM. Я подключилась к базе данных через подключенный уровень, могу получить название таблицы и необходимые поля, но как именно создать класс не знаю.
В EFCore используют некий ModelBuilder, если ли что-нибудь на подобие такого?

Comment: А почему вручную класс не создать?

Comment: Давайте уточним. Вы хотите создать набор классов на основе имеющихся таблиц БД? Смотрите [Data Type mappings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) и [SQL-CLR Type Mapping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/sql-clr-type-mapping) и вручную пишете классы со свойствами, отображающимися на колонки таблиц БД. Если у вас не Sql Server, то поищите аналогичную документацию для своей СУБД.

Comment: Можете попробовать [Entity Framework Core tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet). Установите их глобально и выполните с их помощью scaffolding. Вероятно, придётся почистить, отредактировать получившиеся модели.

Comment: Можете попробовать [T4 Models](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/T4.html) - скрипт генерирует модели для linq2db. Достоинство: поддержка большого количества СУБД.

Comment: Вы можете сказать, что не используете ORM, а я вам их предлагаю. Нет, я предлагаю использовать от этих ORM лишь средства генерации кода.